# iframe a section of a website

Tags: iframe

How would an iframe have to look like showing only the lower part of my website http://www.monero-miner.com/ beneath the "Monero Mining" line?

What I have tried so far:

```
<iframe style=”margin-top: -260px;” src=”monero-miner.com” style=”border:0px #ffffff none;” name=”Monero Mining For Websites” scrolling=”no” frameborder=”1″ height=”1026px” width=”720px” allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: i tried something like this: <iframe style=”margin-top: -260px;” src=”http://monero-miner.com/” style=”border:0px #ffffff none;” name=”Monero Mining For Websites” scrolling=”no” frameborder=”1″ height=”1026px” width=”720px” allowfullscreen></iframe>  but it wont work...